# How do you access a multi-index value in a row of a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a Pandas Dataframe with a 2-level multi-index, and I'm trying to apply a function to the data-frame that does something to depending on the multi-index value for that row, but I haven't found anything online that explains how to that. 
Any ideas?

Comment: It's too general, something more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You can get around a pandas multiIndex with the DataFrame.xs() method, which allows you to specify labels as well as levels when indexing/slicing.
Docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html), but for example-

```
my_multi.xs('x', level=1)
```

on a dataframe that looks like

```
one  two
a    x      00
     y      01
b    x      10
     y      11
```

returns

```
one
a    00
b    10
```